# Social Media Linking

Tags: facebook, integration, interaction, social-media

I've done a little searching and was wondering if there is a way to link a users account in our web app with their social media accounts they choose to link (facebook, twitter, etc). i.e. when they log into our web app they are auto logged into facebook, twitter, etc?

I see facebook has an api to login to our web app using their facebook book account but I want it to work the other way around, I want them logged into facebook when they log into their account via our web app.

Thanks,
Ryan

Comment: In short, you can't.  As far as I know, it is not possible to force a facebook login from your app.  The best you can do is to get them to sign in to facebook via oauth.  But they still need to log in to facebook with their username/password.

Comment: @Gazler - Not entirely correct-see my answer below.

Comment: Ahh, I completely forgot about this feature and was thinking about it from the OAuth point of view.  Cheers for the correction.

Comment: Thanks:) Been hacking on the FB platform for some time now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is definitely possible-from your question I assume you would like to pull data and make actions on behalf of a user? If so, you will need the `offline_access` permission as well as all the other permissions you will need (check out the list [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions) to see exactly which ones you require). Then, you can trigger a script on your server that tell facebook as soon as the user is logged in to your site, to log in your application as the user as well.

**NOTE:** You might be going about this in the wrong way. I would advise that you specify a bit more details on what exactly you need the user to be logged in for, and I can (probably) provide you with a decent answer.

**EDIT:** In response to your question in the comment, Ryan, here is my answer:

You need to divide this problem into 2 different situations-one: your company wants you to write all the code from scratch and don't use what facebook has to offer, in which case you should create a custom login script that enables your users to use their facebook account as the **Actual** user account in your web app. This is the best solution in my opinion, and is supported by the ever-so-awesome [Jeff Atwood](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/11/your-internet-drivers-license.html). [Here's a link to how to do just this](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web#login), [and a tutorial about this also](http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/graph-api-javascript-base-facebook-connect-tutorial/).

Or your company is comfortable with using [Facebook's Social Plugins](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins).
Then you should focus on **[Like Button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like) & [Comments](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments) :** These social plugins are the best way to enable people to create social experiences if they're already logged in.

Comment: @WideBlade - I've been asked to integrate social media into our web app so users in our system can share their experiences with our web app easily on their facebook, twitter etc social media sites. Sometimes w/o having to prompt the user for login credentials to the selected social media site to allow our app to do so (they can opt out via preferences/settings in our web app). I also need a way to record whether the user has successfully linked their facebook, twitter, etc accounts to their account in our web app.

Comment: @Ryan-Hmmp. Tough one. Look at my answer for my opinion.

Comment: @WideBlade - Ok, I reviewed the example and understand it but hmm if the user logs in with their facebook account I'm going to need to pull info from our web apps database about the user for the web app to work... now how do I link a fb account to a user in our web app's database? Via the user id retrieved from facebook?

Comment: @Ryan - Just store the facebook userid, facebook username, your apps's userid and your app's userid in your DB in one row,and so you can just query by any of these four parameters and log in the user.

Comment: @WideBlade - Thank you very much for all your help... you wouldn't happen to know how I could do the same thing with Twitter do you? I have the same connect with Twitter functionality working on my site however I just need to know how to link the twitter account to a user account for my web site?